# How to set applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled to True on a IIS WebApplication (instead of WebSite) with Powershell?

Tags: powershell, iis, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, iis-6

I'm including a Powershell script in my WixToolset installer to do various tasks in IIS, and I can't figure out one thing.

My Site in IIS is structured like this:

- Sites

  - Default Web Site

    - WebApp1
    - WebApp2
    - Identity

I am able to set *applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled* to true on Default Web Site, but I only want to set *preloadEnabled* on my **Identity** WebApplication.

With limited Powershell knowledge, I've tried:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration
Get-WebApplication 
Get-WebApplication "Identity"
```

The code above lists the Identity WebApplication correctly.

```
cd C:\inetpub\wwwroot
Set-ItemProperty "Identity" -Name applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled -Value True
```

The code above gives the error:
The property string applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled=True does not exist or was not found.
At line:1 char:1

I've also tried *preloadEnabled* instead of *applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled*, same result.

Comment: You cant use `Set-Itemproprty` on a normal file path. You need to use the iss path something like IIS:\Sites\SiteName

Comment: Looks like the path I was looking for is "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Identity"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

figured it out thanks to the comment from @guiwhatsthat and some extra searching. This is what worked.

```
Set-ItemProperty "IIS:\Sites\Default Web Site\Identity" -Name preloadEnabled -Value True
```

Comment: The name of the property is "applicationDefaults.preloadEnabled". Specifying "preloadEnabled" will return an error.